# Use Resources in a razor labelfor element

Tags: razor, internationalization, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I added internationalization and resources files, and now want to use some of those resources in the labels for the login for and registration form.

My question is how do I do this? If I just remove the razor code and put in the resource code, the layout is off.

Here is a code fragment:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to change the `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })`part with `@Resources.Resources.RegisterIntro` while keeping the layout as it is.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways 1"direct annotations" 2"Annotatinos with a resource" 
Direct annotations

```
[Display(Name = "My Field")]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

Annotatinos with a resource

```
[Display(Name = "My_Field",ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

Second way will require to add a value in resource file Resource.resx.
Use which suits your purpose.